# Android Wear sleeps when launching Activity from WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wake-lock

I have a handheld application that sends a message to Wear. When the Wear app receives the message, it launches an Activity. The Activity then updates itself shortly after launch based on other factors.

If the Wear device is fully awake when it receives the message, this all works with no problem.

However, if the Wear device is asleep when it receives the incoming message, then one of three things happens:

1. Based on what I see in the log, the Activity is being launched, but isn't visible on the Wear device screen
2. The Activity launches and is visible - but the after-launch update doesn't happen
3. The after-launch update only partially happens

The most common outcome is #3. For example, if the XML has a text field that starts off showing "msg" and the after-launch update changes this text to "message received" - what is actually shown is "mes". In this case, touching the screen wakes up the device and only then does it finish updating the UI.

The implementation of all this includes a WearableListenerService subclass:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

For the purpose of this (simplified) example, I have the Activity starting a thread, waiting 1 second, then making a UI update:

```
public class MessageReceivedActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_received);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
                new UpdateTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "UpdateTask.doInBackground: error sleeping", ex);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mTextView.setText("something else");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following, all with no effect:

- added android:keepScreenOn="true" to the Activity's layout XML
- added  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) in the Activity's onCreate
- acquired a WakeLock in ListenerService.onMessageReceived (for testing purposes, not released until MessageReceivedActivity.onDestroy)

It appears that because Wear only woke up due to the incoming message, it goes back to sleep the instant the UI thread becomes idle - even in spite of a WakeLock. Is there some other way to tell Wear to stay awake?

Comment: android:keepScreenOn="true" works perfectly for me but the difference from your setup is that I do not start the Activity from the Service.

In my app, the Service posts a notification and, when the user clicks an action within the notification, that starts an Activity that has android:keepScreenOn="true" in its layout.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are describing is that your service launches, which wakes up the CPU, but then the CPU goes back to sleep before you have time to complete all your operations.

The solution to this is to use a Wakelock to keep the CPU from sleeping before your operation completes. Can you post your Wakelock code?

Also make sure you have permission. ;)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I ultimately had to abandon this approach. Instead of having the Service launch the Activity directly, instead the Service generates a notification. The Activity can then be launched from the notification. So I no longer have the original code available to post here. However, the general idea was that I was acquiring the wakelock as soon as the message was received, then (at least just for testing purposes) releasing it when the launched Activity was destroyed. I did have the permission line in the manifest. Unfortunately, it still did not work.

Comment: Glad you got it working but a couple of hours hi go to note for next time.. The wakelock will stay awake to run any code in the current thread.  but if you were then posting any non synchronous background tasks from the wakelock,  then that is not guaranteed to complete before the wakelock is released.

Comment: The partial wakelock might be especially useful if you just need to update some data in the background and don't need the user to interact with the app/activity.